# If $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge then $c_n = 2a_n - 5b_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here is my attempt at the proof.

Suppose that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be ABF and let $\varepsilon_1 = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ and $\varepsilon_2 = \frac{\varepsilon}{10}$. Then we know there exists $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N_1$ we have that $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon_1 = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ and for all $n > N_2$ we have that $|b_n - b| < \varepsilon_2 = \frac{\varepsilon}{10}$. Then $|2a_n - 2a| < 2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ and $|5b_n - 5b| < 5\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{10}$. Let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for all $n > N$ we have that

$$\begin{split}
|c_n - (2a - 5b)| &= |(2a_n - 5b_n) - (2a - 5b)|\\
& = |(2a_n - 2a) - (5b_n - 5b)|\\
&\leq |2a_n - 2a| + |5b_n - 5b|\\
&< 2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{4} + 5\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\\
&= \varepsilon\\\
\end{split}$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is $c_n=2a_n+5b_n$ or $2a_n-5b_n$?

Comment: Sorry about that. $c_n = 2a_n - 5b_n$.

Comment: So the first line of your multi-line equation should have $(2a\color{red}-5b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are completely correct.